# Space complexity on a trivial example

Tags: python, space-complexity

So I was checking the codibility website for online code evaluation. I tried the demo example http://codility.com/c/intro/demoRVC9C9-W8X to familiarize myself with the system.

> A zero-indexed array A consisting of N different integers is given.
>   The array contains integers in the range [1..(N + 1)], which means
>   that exactly one element is missing. Your goal is to find that missing
>   element. Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
>
> that, given a zero-indexed array A, returns the value of the
>   missing element. For example, given array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 2
>   A[1] = 3
>   A[2] = 1
>   A[3] = 5
>
> the function should return 4, as it is
>   the missing element. Assume that: N is an integer within the range
>   [0..100,000]; the elements of A are all distinct; each element of
>   array A is an integer within the range [1..(N + 1)].
>
> Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
>
> expected worst-case space complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
>
> Elements of input arrays can be
>   modified.

Here is my solution in Python:

```
def solution(A):
  tmp = [ 0 for x in xrange( len(A) + 1 ) ]
  for i,x in enumerate( A ):
    tmp[ x - 1 ] = 1
  return 1 + tmp.index( 0 )
```

I was pretty sure that my solution would NOT be accepted because the space complexity is O(n) where n is the size of A. However the system accepted my answer with a perfect score. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Indeed your solution has linear memory complexity. I don't know how codility analyzes this, but you are right. PS: Maybe a more clever approach will be summing the array and substract it from (n*(n+1)/2)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It's really weird that the demo example isn't evaluated correctly. Btw your solution is elegant, thanks.

Comment: I, too, agree your solution doesn't seem to meet the O(n) space complexity requirement. Regardless, the only way I can think to avoid that with any solution would be to modify the input array if additional storage was needed (and the question says is allowable).

Comment: @martineau: You can solve it without additional storage

Comment: @BeniBela: Yes, I know. The question is why did the website's system accept the OP's solution which doesn't appear to have O(1) space complexity.

Comment: The question does say "beyond input storage" implying you can store the input? Eg make a copy of it, which technically is o(n) space complexity however if you ignore this it makes the solution o(1). Perhaps that is why it passes the test.

Answer (score 0):

My solution takes it's base from a ruby perspective.

## in ruby

```
def solution(a)
  (1..(a.count+1)).select{|x| !a.include?(x)}.first
end
```

## in python

```
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 2.7
    return filter(lambda x: (x not in A), range(1, (len(A)+2)))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution resulted 100/100

```
def solution(A):

if not A:
    return 1
sumz=sum(xrange(1,(max(A)+1)))
if ((len(A)+1)) not in A:
    return len(A)+1

a_sum=sum(A)

return sumz-a_sum
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution in Ruby.

```
def solution(a)    
  return 1 if a.empty?
  ac = a.count
  ((ac+1)*(ac+2))/2 - a.inject(0, :+)
end
```

.inject(0, :+) sums up elements in array.

Answer (score -1):

Just start lernig Python and this is my 100 score solution:

```
def solution(A):
    a=[]
    a=A
    a.sort()
    b=0
    if len(a)<1:
        return 1
    if a[0] != 1:
        return 1
    else:
        for x in xrange(0,len(a)):
            b=b+int(a[x])
    if a[len(a)-1]==len(a)+1:        
        c=(1+len(a))*len(a)/2
        d=b-a[len(a)-1]
        e=c-d
        return e
    else:
        return len(a)+1
```

i know its not great im just start lerning Python

Answer (score -1):

these are two complicated scenarios.

think simply.

step #1: order the array
step #2: iterate trough the ordered array. if A[i] != i+1 you have fund the missing element. in case the loop iterates through the whole array than the last element is missing just return the last element + 1.

this is 100% solution.